# Firebird - Broken Trigger

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a database containing two tables.  An ON INSERT trigger in Table ITEMS is supposed to add the value of ITEMS.ITEMSIZE to STATS.SIZE

The select statement below is the problem.  How do I modify this to only get the ITEMSIZE of the current row being updated.  BTW the STATS table only has a single row.

```
** Tables **

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
    ID              ID NOT NULL /* ID = VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL */,
    EXPIRYTIME      EXPIRYTIME NOT NULL /* EXPIRYTIME = BIGINT NOT NULL */,
    ITEMSIZE        ITEMSIZE /* ITEMSIZE = BIGINT NOT NULL */,
    ACCESSCOUNT     ACCESSCOUNT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL /* ACCESSCOUNT = INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL */,
    LASTACCESSTIME  LASTACCESSTIME /* LASTACCESSTIME = TIMESTAMP NOT NULL */
);


CREATE TABLE STATS (
    INSTANCE            SMALLINT,
    SIZE                BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    DISKCACHEITEMCOUNT  BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    DISKCACHEHITS       BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    DISKCACHEMISSES     BIGINT DEFAULT 0
);
```

** Trigger **

```
AS
DECLARE ITEM_SIZE bigint;
begin
SELECT ITEMSIZE FROM ITEMS INTO :ITEM_SIZE;
UPDATE STATS SET SIZE = SIZE  + :ITEM_SIZE WHERE INSTANCE = '0';
end
```

Comment: Does Firebird have `OLD` and `NEW` for the old row values and new row values inside triggers? That's the usual way it works but I don't know Firebird.

Comment: I assume you mean something like. SELECT new.ITEMSIZE FROM ITEMS INTO :ITEM_SIZE; Same problem.

Comment: Perhaps `UPDATE STATS SET SIZE = SIZE + NEW.ITEMSIZE WHERE INSTANCE = '0';` would work, then drop `:ITEMSIZE` completely. That's probably what I'd do in PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: Tried that but it wont compile. I think its because UPDATE is referring to a different table.

Comment: @MU thanks for the hints you where on the right track.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy as long as you got it all sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user "mu is too short" gave you right hint - you want to use NEW / OLD context variables in the trigger to read the values of the "current record". So your trigger would be something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddItemSize FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 100
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE STATS SET SIZE = SIZE + NEW.ITEMSIZE WHERE INSTANCE = 0;
END
```

Comment: Thanks but again it does'nt compile.  "Column does not belong to referenced table. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -206. Colum unknown. INSTANCE. At line 6, column 75."

Comment: Well, do you actually have the column named "INSTANCE" in the STATS table? Check the spelling. BTW did you use quoted identifers when you created the table? In that case the field name in the trigger must be quoted too and you have to use the exact case you used in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition you check whether the SMALLINT INSTANCE is 0, but you write INSTANCE='0' - which checks whether it is a '0'-valued VARCHAR. Try changing it to INSTANCE=0.